# Meteor Mongo error

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have just set up a meteor localhost app, and when trying to execute "`meteor mongo`" on the linux terminal, it shows this error:

```
mongo: Meteor isn't running a local MongoDB server.

This command only works while Meteor is running your application locally. Start
your application first. (This error will also occur if you asked Meteor to use
a different MongoDB server with $MONGO_URL when you ran your application.)

If you're trying to connect to the database of an app you deployed with
'meteor deploy', specify your site's name with this command.
```

What should I do??

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much what it says:

Run `meteor` in one terminal.

Run `meteor mongo` in another terminal while the first one is still running.