# Meteor Mongo Error

Tags: mongodb

I have just set up a meteor localhost app, and when trying to execute "meteor mongo" on the linux terminal, it shows this error:

```
mongo: Meteor isn't running a local MongoDB server.

This command only works while Meteor is running your application locally. Start
your application first. (This error will also occur if you asked Meteor to use
a different MongoDB server with $MONGO_URL when you ran your application.)

If you're trying to connect to the database of an app you deployed with
'meteor deploy', specify your site's name with this command.
What sould I do??
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor Mongo error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486016/meteor-mongo-error)

Answer (score 1):

you need to have mongo server running to run meteor mongo and access it.
first open a terminal window and run your meteor app

```
meteor run
```

then open another window and access your mongo db

```
meteor mongo
```